# Joomla 4 - How to Store Session Variables

Tags: php, joomla, joomla4

The `getSession()` function is now deprecated in

> [Joomla 4](https://www.joomla.org/4/en/)

The documentation does not seem to make any reference to this functionality and other resource material just seem few and far between.

I will like to know how to store session variables in Joomla 4 and also wayss of retrieving stored session variables.

For example, when storing session variable in a standard php app, `serialize()` is used when storing objects, and a call to `unserialize()` is used to retrieve the object from session.

**Sample code to store object**

```
session_start();
$obj = new Object();
$_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($obj);
```

**Sample code to retrieve object**

```
session_start();
$session = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);
```

**In Joomla prior to Joomla 4**

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', "value");
```

Now you can retrieve this session variable using:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('name');
```

How can I perform similar functionality in Joomla 4 and above? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Joomla\CMS\Session\Session;

Session::start();//if not already started
Session::set('name', 'value');
```